# How do I use for loop like php in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Well, I need to use following code to Javascript base on a php value (int):

```
$("div#toggle1 a.button").click(function ()
$("div#toggle1 div.box").toggle("slow");

$("div#toggle2 a.button").click(function ()
$("div#toggle2 div.box").toggle("slow");

$("div#toggle3 a.button").click(function ()
$("div#toggle3 div.box").toggle("slow");

$("div#toggle4 a.button").click(function ()
$("div#toggle4 div.box").toggle("slow");
```

so that I'm using following code to achieve it but...can't work for my lack of javascript knowledge..

```
for (i = 0; i <= <?php echo $num; ?>; i++) {
    $("div#toggle" .  i .  "a.button").click(function () {
        $("div#toggle1" .  i .  " div.box").toggle("slow");
    });
```

Comment: How is your HTML like?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= '<?php echo (int)$num; ?>'); i++) {
    $("div#toggle" + i + "a.button").click(function () {
        $("div#toggle1" + i + " div.box").toggle("slow");
    });
}
```

Use `+` to concat the strings and use `Number()` to convert `string` to `Number`

Comment: I'm trying with this..Thank You.

Comment: In source code I can't see the `i` value that's why seems not working.

Comment: @RPM, I don't know php. Does it automatically produce a number?

Comment: No, it is probably a string, but you can cast it to an integer.

Comment: @AmitJoki It's not working. In source code i can't see the value of `i`

Comment: @Babu if you need to do this, something is wrong with your architecture, consider refactoring, using AJAX, if necessary.